# php add file to zip returning blank files

Tags: php

I am having an issue with the below code (it works fine on local).

I am using this for an image gallery to download a selection of images using a checkbox. Anyways, this is working fine on my localhost but when I execute this code on my live site it downloads a zip file with the correct file names but the the files are blank.

Any suggestions to why this may be happening?

```
<?php

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names, $archive_file_name, $file_path)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }

    foreach ($file_names as $files) {
        # download file
        $download_file = file_get_contents($files);

        #add it to the zip
        $zip->addFromString(basename($files), $download_file);
    }

    $zip->close();
    $zipped_size = filesize($archive_file_name);
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Length:" . " $zipped_size");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    unlink("$archive_file_name"); // Now delete the temp file on the server
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
    //$file_names=$_POST['files'];// 
    //$file_names = filter_var_array($_POST['files']);//works but it's the wrong method
    $filter = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); //sanitise files
    $file_names = $filter['files'];
    //Archive name
    $archive_file_name = 'product-images.zip';
    //Download Files path
    $file_path = getcwd() . '';
    //cal the function
    zipFilesAndDownload($file_names, $archive_file_name, $file_path);
} else {

    header("Refresh: 5; url= ./index.php ");
    print '<h1 style="text-align:center">You you shouldn\'t be here ......</pre>
    <p style="color: red;"><strong>redirection in 5 seconds</strong></p>
    <pre>';
    exit;
}
?>
```

edit: i see this in my php error log:

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jig/download-product-images.php on line 19
```

Comment: Can you check if the configuration of your live server is the same as of your development environment? There are settings that can disable `file_get_contents()` like `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: Do the image files exist on your live server ?

Comment: Yes images exist on live server as when a checkbox is ticked it gets the image url of the image.

Comment: @AdamBenedek allow_url_fopen is enabled, but allow_url_include is disabled for security.